# What is the maximum size of bars in a barchart?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Bar chart in my crystal report. In one scenario I am getting 84 bars in a bar chart. Data values are overlapping with each other. I tried to increase chart size but didn't work. Can you tell me what is the maximum limit of bars so that I can limit my data to display bars with Data labels.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum limit of bars. The display result of your chart depends on the modification of some parameters like the bar width, the gap between them, the width of your page, the orientation etc. For example here you can see a barchart with 269 bars
[image]

It has to do with what you want. I advise you to preview your chart and try many changes to your Chart Options until you have the needed result. You can also show us a snapshot with your result to give you more specific advice.